# Base64 to PDF in Javascript to new tab

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64

I'm looking for a simple javascript Base64 to PDF in new tab code, I haven't found a version that does this from a base64 encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base 64 encoded pdf to new pdf in a new tab which is downloadable:

```
function base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
  const bString = window.atob(data);
  const bLength = bString.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(bLength);
  for (let i = 0; i < bLength; i++) {
      bytes[i] = bString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes;
}
function base64toPDF(base64EncodedData, fileName = 'file') {
  const bufferArray = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64EncodedData);
  const blobStore = new Blob([bufferArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobStore);
      return;
  }
  const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobStore);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.href = data;
  link.download = `${fileName}.pdf`;
  link.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
  link.remove();
}
```